FileNotFoundError when loading SQuAD dataset with datasets library
I am trying to load the SQuAD dataset using the datasets library in Python, but I am encountering a FileNotFoundError. Here is the code I am using:
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("squad")

However, this results in the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   
File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1797, in load_dataset     **config_kwargs,   File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1520, in load_dataset_builder     
data_files=data_files,   File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 1164, in dataset_module_factory     
path, data_dir=data_dir, data_files=data_files, download_mode=download_mode   
File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 645, in get_module     
allowed_extensions=ALL_ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS,   
File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py", line 798, in from_local_or_remote     
if not isinstance(patterns_for_key, DataFilesList)   
File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py", line 748, in from_local_or_remote     
data_files = resolve_patterns_locally_or by_urls(base_path, patterns, allowed_extensions)   File "/root/miniconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py", line 355, in resolve_patterns_locally_or_by_urls     
raise FileNotFoundError(error_msg) FileNotFoundError: Unable to resolve any data file that matches '['**']' at /root/retraining-free-pruning/squad with any supported extension ['.csv', 
'.tsv', '.json', '.jsonl', '.parquet', '.arrow', '.txt', '.blp', '.bmp', '.dib', '.bufr', 
'.cur', '.pcx', '.dcx', '.dds', '.ps', '.eps', '.fit', '.fits', '.fli', '.flc', '.ftc', 
'.ftu', '.gbr', '.gif', '.grib', '.h5', '.hdf', '.png', '.apng', '.jp2', '.j2k', '.jpc', 
'.jpf', '.jpx', '.j2c', '.icns', '.ico', '.im', '.iim', '.tif', '.tiff', '.jfif', '.jpe', 
'.jpg', '.jpeg', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.msp', '.pcd', '.pxr', '.pbm', '.pgm', '.ppm', '.pnm', 
'.psd', '.bw', '.rgb', '.rgba', '.sgi', '.ras', '.tga', '.icb', '.vda', '.vst', '.webp', 
'.wmf', '.emf', '.xbm', '.xpm', '.BLP', '.BMP', '.DIB', '.BUFR', '.CUR', '.PCX', '.DCX', 
'.DDS', '.PS', '.EPS', '.FIT', '.FITS', '.FLI', '.FLC', '.FTC', '.FTU', '.GBR', '.GIF', 
'.GRIB', '.H5', '.HDF', '.PNG', '.APNG', '.JP2', '.J2K', '.JPC', '.JPF', '.JPX', '.J2C', 
'.ICNS', '.ICO', '.IM', '.IIM', '.TIF', '.TIFF', '.JFIF', '.JPE', '.JPG', '.JPEG', '.MPG', 
'.MPEG', '.MSP', '.PCD', '.PXR', '.PBM', '.PGM', '.PPM', '.PNM', '.PSD', '.BW', '.RGB', 
'.RGBA', '.SGI', '.RAS', '.TGA', '.ICB', '.VDA', '.VST', '.WEBP', '.WMF', '.EMF', '.XBM', 
'.XPM', '.aiff', '.au', '.avr', '.caf', '.flac', '.htk', '.svx', '.mat4', '.mat5', '.mpc2k',
 '.ogg', '.paf', '.pvf', '.raw', '.rf64', '.sd2', '.sds', '.ircam', '.voc', '.w64', '.wav', 
'.nist', '.wavex', '.wve', '.xi', '.mp3', '.opus', '.AIFF', '.AU', '.AVR', '.CAF', '.FLAC', 
'.HTK', '.SVX', '.MAT4', '.MAT5', '.MPC2K', '.OGG', '.PAF', '.PVF', '.RAW', '.RF64', '.SD2', 
'.SDS', '.IRCAM', '.VOC', '.W64', '.WAV', '.NIST', '.WAVEX', '.WVE', '.XI', '.MP3', '.OPUS', 
'.zip']

It seems like the code is trying to find the SQuAD dataset in my local directory instead of downloading it. I am not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.
How can I correctly load the SQuAD dataset using the datasets library without encountering this FileNotFoundError? What steps do I need to take to resolve this issue?

Python version: 3.7
datasets library version: 2.13.2

It runs successfully on Colab but not success on autodl cloud GPU platforms. It doesn't seem to be an internet connectivity issue; rather, it appears that some required files or configurations are not being found. And I tried Glue datasets, load_dataset() could find the link and give me the error massage, but squad just give me they could not find files. I don't know the reason.

Update the datasets library: make sure you have the latest version of the datasets library. Update it using pip:
pip install --upgrade datasets

Check Internet Connectivity: even though you mentioned it is not an internet connectivity issue, it’s good to double-check:
import requests
try:
    requests.get("http://www.google.com", timeout=5)
    print("Internet connection is working")
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("No internet connection available.")

Try specifying the dataset repository: explicitly specify the dataset repository source when loading the dataset. This can sometimes resolve path issues.
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("squad", cache_dir="/path/to/cache")

Clear the cache: sometimes, clearing the cache directory of the datasets library can resolve the issue.
from datasets import load_dataset
from datasets import config
cache_dir = config.HF_DATASETS_CACHE
print(f"Clearing cache directory: {cache_dir}")
import shutil shutil.rmtree(cache_dir)
# Reload the dataset
dataset = load_dataset("squad")

Manually download and load the dataset:
If the above steps do not work, you can manually download the dataset from its source and load it using the local files.
Download the SQuAD dataset from the SQuAD website or directly from Hugging Face.
Load the dataset locally:
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files='path_to_local_squad.json')

Check environment settings:
ensure there are no environment variables or settings that might interfere with the path resolution.
Network Proxy:
if you are behind a corporate firewall or using a proxy, configure the environment to handle it. You might need to set up proxy settings if necessary:
import os
os.environ['http_proxy'] = 'http://your.proxy.com:port'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'http://your.proxy.com:port'

Here's an example with all the steps combined for clarity:
Ensure the datasets library is updated:
pip install --upgrade datasets

Check internet connectivity:
import requests
try:
    requests.get("http://www.google.com", timeout=5)
    print("Internet connection is working")
except requests.ConnectionError:
    print("No internet connection available.")

Load the SQuAD dataset with a specified cache directory:
```python
from datasets import load_dataset
try:
    dataset = load_dataset("squad", cache_dir="/path/to/cache")
    print("SQuAD dataset loaded successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error loading SQuAD dataset: {e}")

Clear the cache and try again:
from datasets import config
import shutil
cache_dir = config.HF_DATASETS_CACHE
print(f"Clearing cache directory: {cache_dir}")
shutil.rmtree(cache_dir)

try:
    dataset = load_dataset("squad", cache_dir="/path/to/cache")
    print("SQuAD dataset loaded successfully after clearing cache")
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error loading SQuAD dataset after clearing cache: {e}")

As a fallback, download manually and load locally:
dataset = load_dataset('json', data_files='path_to_local_squad.json')
print("SQuAD dataset loaded successfully from local files")

Make sure to replace "path_to_local_squad.json" with the actual path to the downloaded SQuAD dataset file on your local machine. If you continue to experience issues, please provide additional context or error messages so I can assist further.
